# NestJS: class-validator Not Throwing Validation Errors for Casted Objects

Tags: javascript, nestjs, dto, class-validator

To start with the example code:

```
// anniversarycredits.dto.ts

export class AnniversaryCreditsDto {
  @IsNumber()
  @ApiProperty({
    description: 'The amount of credits to award on anniversary.',
  })
  'creditAmount': number;

  @IsString()
  @IsOptional()
  @ApiProperty({ description: 'The name (appearance only) of this benefit.' })
  'name': string;

  @IsString()
  @IsOptional()
  @ApiProperty({
    description: 'The description of this benefit (appearance only).',
  })
  'description': string;

  @Equals('ANNIVERSARY_CREDITS')
  @IsOptional()
  @ApiProperty({
    description: 'This is an internal identifier, leave default.',
  })
  'type' = 'ANNIVERSARY_CREDITS';
}
```

```
// benefits.controller.ts (snippet)

@Patch()
  update(
    @Req() req: any,
    @Body()
    updateBenefitData: any,
  ): Promise<ResponseDto> {
    switch (updateBenefitData.type) {
      case 'ANNIVERSARY_CREDITS':
        return this.benefitsService.update(
          req._merchantId,
          updateBenefitData as AnniversaryCreditsDto,
        );
```

As you can see, I have class-validator tags set up on the dto that I am casting to. class-validator works in all other cases except for cases I am casting. In casting, it throws no errors and allows any input.

I have tried searching around for answers, can't seem to find anyone that ran into this same issue. I looked into the possibility of constructing all of the objects rather than casting, but it didn't seem like validator runs when constructed with `new`. Any input is appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[class-validator](https://github.com/typestack/class-validator), as its name suggests, works on class instances. Nest makes it *seemingly* work on regular objects through some clever use of parameter metadata reflection and its [ValidationPipe](https://github.com/nestjs/nest/blob/master/packages/common/pipes/validation.pipe.ts) which uses `class-transformer` to take the incoming object and translate it into a class instance. *Then* the instance has `validate` (from class-validator) called on it, and the *instance* has its property metadata read so that each property can be properly validated.

Casting, as you're doing here, is only telling the compiler "Look, I know that this variable is this value, trust me". It has no runtime meaning, and all you have is an object at that point. Similarly, as you use `any` type for the `@Body()` parameter, the `ValidaitonPipe` looks at the metadata and goes "Dunno what this is" and returns the value directly, as there's no instance it can knowingly turn it in to for validation.

If you need to keep with this `any` approach, 1) think about using `unknown` instead,and 2) translate the object into an instance of the `AnniversaryCreditsDto` and *then* use `validate` from `class-validator` to see if the object has any errors according to your decorations.

Comment: After some research, I did indeed find out that casting wasn't even *really* a thing in TypeScript, so understood on that part. I think I do need to keep the `any` approach (~10 similar objects with different data requirements that should not be individual endpoints), so would I use `class-transformer` to translate the obj to a given instance? Or is there another preferred method? Thanks so much for the reply!

**EDIT:** Also, its seems to be the case that if I use unknown I cant access any data from the object? I need to decide on the object type based on a property in the req body.

Comment: You could use `class-transformer` to create the instance from the body, yes. You'd have to tell the `plainToInstance` method what class to transform to. `unknown` is a special type in typescript that's incredibly strict, forcing you to check for types and properties before trying to access them. any just allows you to access whatever you want whether its there or not and can lead to runtime issues. [more on the unknown type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#unknown)

Comment: Got it all to work using your suggestions! Thanks so much for the help. I didn't need to use `unknown`, though perhaps that would have been for the best. I used the `plainToInstance()` function to create the intended instance type based on the field and passed that object as `any` to my service. Within the service, I make the `validate` call and return out of the function if an error is returned. Its a lot more code, but it works and that is what is important haha. Thanks again.